# Why does this Angular filter get applied to LIKE ids?

Tags: angularjs

I have a series of 3 selects that remove options that are selected in the other fields.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iduBwP9AdSWr2lbaSbvd?p=preview)

```
<label>Choice 1</label>
<select ng-model="food.fruitOne"
        ng-options="fruit.id as fruit.name for fruit in fruits | filter:food.fruitTwo!=''?{id: '!' + food.fruitTwo}:{} | filter:food.fruitThree!=''? {id: '!' + food.fruitThree}:{}">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<label>Choice 2</label>
<select ng-model="food.fruitTwo"
        ng-options="fruit.id as fruit.name for fruit in fruits | filter: food.fruitOne!=''?{id: '!' + food.fruitOne}:{} | filter: food.fruitThree!=''?{id: '!' + food.fruitThree}:{}">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<label>Choice 3</label>
<select ng-model="food.fruitThree"
        ng-options="fruit.id as fruit.name for fruit in fruits | filter: food.fruitOne!=''?{id: '!' + food.fruitOne}:{} | filter: food.fruitTwo!=''?{id: '!' + food.fruitTwo}:{}">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Works great except this issue;

It seems to filter like ids.  So if 1 is selected, items with 1x id also get filtered from subsequent selects.  Same with other similar ids - 2 & 2x.

Clearly I am not being explicit enough.  What's missing?

Thanks!

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/gzuhYYX2P1Wd0OtfLgOU?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @maurycy, will give that a whirl.

Comment: That was it thanks pal!

Comment: You wanna submit as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter can accept function that could be useful in your case since you have to handle 3 different cases

```
 $scope.filterFruitsA = function(val) {
    return val.id !== val.id !== $scope.food.fruitTwo && val.id !== $scope.food.fruitThree
  }
  $scope.filterFruitsB = function(val) {
    return val.id !== $scope.food.fruitOne && val.id !== $scope.food.fruitThree
  }
  $scope.filterFruitsC = function(val) {
    return val.id !== $scope.food.fruitOne && val.id !== $scope.food.fruitTwo
  }
```

Link to working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/gzuhYYX2P1Wd0OtfLgOU?p=preview

I'm sure it could be done in a clever way but at that time of the day I can't think of anything, I'll try and revisit this question tomorrow